# how to emplace_back (append) in vector without declaring variables..?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++17

If number of input are given as first input.
If I need to store them in vector
I can easily do it by creating a variable and using the variable I can append it in the vector 
I'm fascinated to know , is there any other way so that I need not have to use a variable..

**INPUT**

```
4
1 5 3 2
```

How vector take inputs

```
vector<int>vec;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    int x;
    cin>>x;    // any idea to remove using a variable here..?
    vec.emplace_back(x);
}
```

How array takes inputs

```
int array[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
cin>>array[i];
```

Comment: Note: In `int array[n];`, `n` must be a compile time constant in Standard C++. The 4 in the file doesn't qualify as a compile time constant.

Comment: `int get_int(istream& in) { int x; if (!(in >> x)) throw runtime_error("input error"); return x; }` and then `vec.emplace_back(get_int(cin));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just do this:

```
std::cin >> vec.emplace_back();
```

The return type of [`vector::emplace_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) in C++17 is no longer `void`. Instead, it returns a reference to the inserted element. So `vec.emplace_back()` will construct an element by default and return its reference.

Comment: And if `operator>>` fails then you have an unassigned element left behind in your vector.

Answer (score 0):

Or using STL algorithm (works with C++03):

```cpp
vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(n); // good practice to reduce reallocation of memory
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>{std::cin}, n, std::back_inserter(vec));
```